# Lookup a value in a range

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, lookup

SQL newbie here. I am attempting to get the appropriate Age Category based on the Age at List from the AgeBrackets tables using the between function.

GetAgeCategory query:

```
SELECT TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUM,  TRANSACTIONS.Age at List, Age Category.AgeBrackets 
FROM TRANSACTIONS, AgeBrackets
WHERE 
(((TRANSACTIONS.Age at List) Between [AgeBrackets].FROM and [AgeBrackets].TO));
```

I did a count on the TRANSACTIONS table and there are more records on that table compared to the GetAgeCategory query.  For some reason the query is excluding records from the TRANSACTIONS table. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which RDBMS using..?

Comment: what kind of syntax is this? MS Access SQL does not really look like this.

Comment: I am using MS Access and there is a typo.The select portion should be:    SELECT TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUM,  TRANSACTIONS.[Age at List], Age Category.[AgeBrackets]

Answer (score 0):

Your Select Query syntax is not MS access's sql syntax and your delimitation of Age is not correctly formulated.

Try separating AgeBrackets into two fields, one containing lower boundary and one containing upper boundary then use this SQL:

```
SELECT TRANSACTIONS.ACCOUNT_NUM,  TRANSACTIONS.Age at List, Age Category.AgeBracketsLower, Age Category.AgeBracketsUpper 
FROM TRANSACTIONS, AgeBrackets
WHERE 
(((TRANSACTIONS.Age at List) Between [AgeBracketsLower] TO [AgeBracketsUpper]));
```

You have to establish clear lower and upper boundaries when using between. You shouldn't use one field for both boundaries because access will not distinguish the difference.
Correct:
Between 1 and 5
Between 2000 and 2016
Between number1 and number2
Your statement:
Between [AgeBrackets] TO [AgeBrackets] is traduced roughly to Between 1 to 1

Comment: Excellent, please mark this as a correct answer and we are done, have a good day.